# SDL2 with C undefined reference to `IMG_Load'

Tags: c, sdl-2

I am programming in C using SDL2 and I am getting this error:

```
`main': main.c:(.text+0x2d0): undefined reference to 'IMG_Load'`
```

I have these includes:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

For reference I am using Arch Linux and using GCC with this command to compile:

```
gcc main.c `sdl2-config --libs -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image` -o game
```

I've looked all over for solutions but none of them seem to rectify the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
gcc main.c `sdl2-config --libs -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image` -o game
```

should be:

```
gcc main.c `sdl2-config --libs` -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -o game
```

In other words, only `sdl2-config --libs` is the subcommand.

Comment: That worked, thank you! I was unaware that those parts were supposed to be separate.